# What is the syntax to make a factory with an association that uses a trait?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I'm really trying to wrap my head around how to create complicated factories with Factory Girl, and it is ***NOT*** easy.

I have the following:

- Subscription belongs_to User
- Subscription belongs_to Plan

I want to test different `Plans`. Here is how I set it up:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :plan do
    trait :copper do
      name          { "Copper" }
      amount        { 5 }
      stripe_id     { "Economy" }
      listing_limit { 10 }
      repositories_allowed { 1 }
    end
    trait :copper_multi do
      name          { "Copper Multi" }
      amount        { 10 }
      stripe_id     { "Copper_Multi" }
      listing_limit { 10 }
      repositories_allowed { 5 }
    end
    trait :bronze do
      name          { "Bronze" }
      amount        { 5 }
      stripe_id     { "Basic" }
      listing_limit { 10 }
      repositories_allowed { 1 }
    end
    trait :bronze_multi do
      name          { "Bronze Multi" }
      amount        { 10 }
      stripe_id     { "Basic_Multi" }
      listing_limit { 10 }
      repositories_allowed { 5 }
    end
  end
end
```

`Subscription` factory is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscription do
    association :user
    association :plan
    start_date { Time.now }
    end_date { 365.days.from_now }
  end

end
```

Naturally, this fails, because the `Plan` factory can't be used without also specifying a trait. This is by design.

Also, what is the difference between:

```
  factory :subscription do
    association :user
  end
```

and:

```
  factory :subscription do
    user
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a default plan

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :plan do
    name          { "Default" }
    amount        { 1 }
    stripe_id     { "Default" }
    listing_limit { 10 }
    repositories_allowed { 1 }

    trait :copper do
      name          { "Copper" }
      amount        { 5 }
      stripe_id     { "Economy" }
      listing_limit { 10 }
      repositories_allowed { 1 }
    end
  end
end
```

Now this should work

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscription do
    association :user
    association :plan
    start_date { Time.now }
    end_date { 365.days.from_now }
  end
end
```

If you want to create a subscription with specific trait(copper) for plan

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscription do
    association :user
    association :plan, :factory => [:plan, :copper]
    start_date { Time.now }
    end_date { 365.days.from_now }
  end
end
```

There is no difference between

```
factory :subscription do
    association :user
  end
```

and

```
factory :subscription do
  user
end
```

But you can use the later only if the association name and the factory name matches